# Compare the content of two char arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, string-comparison

I have a problem when I try to compare the content of two char arrays.
Sometimes 
If the string is less than the actual size of the array, in it there is no sequence of '\0' but often there are unexpected characters (in the xcode debug there was the '\x01' character and in the control loop I use To check if a memory cell of the array was the same as the other, it was not the same). So to overcome this problem I decided to force the user to write the array content exactly as array size(-1): ex. array[3], the users write "hi" (without the ""). So I was wondering if there is a way to compare the two strings (I'm not talking about length but content) without fully filling the array in order to compare the content ofenter code here the two arrays through a simple cycle. (I was thinking of initializing the vector with \ 0 but I do not know if there can be problems)
thanks for the answers

this is an example of the code

```
}while(sent !=1);


for(contatore=0; contatore<MAXNOME; contatore++){

    if(UserName[contatore] ==  persona.username[contatore]){

        controlloUsr++;
    }

}


for(contatore=0; contatore<MAXNOME; contatore++){

    if(password[contatore] ==  persona.password[contatore]){

                    controlloPsw++;
    }

}


if(controlloUsr == MAXNOME && controlloPsw == MAXPSW){

   return 1;

} else {

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. There is not enough information in the question.

Comment: We need to know how the variables uses are defined and initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but there is no way to browse an array of chars in C without giving the code a stop sequence, like a \0, or you will browse it forever (well, until a wild segfault appear...)

You can write your own strncmp function for this, something like :

```
int my_strncmp(char *str1, char *str2, size_t max, char c)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while (n < max)
    {
         if ((str1[n] != str2[n]) || (str1[n] == c) || (str2[n] == c))
             return 0;
         n++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This will return 0 if your char c is met, or if the strings are different, or 1 if the string are the same until max char. Just be sure that one of the two conditions is met or you code will crash into a segfault / have undefined behavior, since you will browse out of your allowed memory range.

Comment: A C string must by definition be terminated by a `\0` character, which is itself part of the string. `max` should be of type `size_t`, which is the correct type for array indices, and `my_strnlen()` should return type `size_t`; this is also the type returned by the library `strlen()` family of functions. Code may or may not segfault after out-of-bounds access; behavior is undefined.

Comment: Why is this function called `my_strnlen()`? It does not return a length, but is a comparison function.

Comment: Thanks ! Updated answer with your comments

Comment: With my initial comment I had not realized that you had written a string comparison function (hasty reading, and `my_strnlen()` function name). Note that the [`strcmp()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4.4) family of functions return an `int`: negative, zero, or positive, which indicates the ordering of the strings. Also note that there is no need for the stop character `c`, since strings must be null-terminated.

Comment: Fixed the return value; I think OP want some kind of strncmp which work for non-terminated arrays of char, so the name strncmp is indeed ill-advised, since OP doesn't seem to be talking about strings, im not sure what to call it.

Answer (score 1):

the function `strcmp()`  and the `strncmp()` are made for this exact operation,.

You can read the `man` page for those two functions for all the details.